# Need standard naming description of shape of mirrors on wardrobe

Tags: furniture, design, mirror

Is there a standard naming convention for this type of mirror on a wardrobe, as this pic shows?

[image: mirrors on wardrobe]

This standard name will help me use search engines to find similar mirrors to buy.

Google Lens search on this photo wasn't useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That style of panel, whether it's a cabinet door or some other type of furniture, is typically called **Cathedral**.
Note that depending on where you are in the world there are certainly bound to be other local/colloquial names for it.

[image]